# Replacing "android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout" with another one for can be showing that on Preview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

As all we know, there is a problem with `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` on the Preview Of Android Studio and we cannot see anything with this `"android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout"`.

So, this is so bad and take our time so much for designing an activity.

My question is,

Is there any replacer for doing this with below tutorial?
***(For showing the Preview on Android Studio)***

http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html

For example, here is my **Main_activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="7dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar">
        </include>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="155dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/outer_margin">
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/bg"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <Button
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:text="@string/button"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/outer_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/outer_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/outer_margin">
            <TextView
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title2"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/outer_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/outer_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/outer_margin">
            <TextView
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title3"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/outer_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/outer_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/outer_margin">
        <TextView
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title4"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/outer_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/outer_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/outer_margin">
            <TextView
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title4"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Build.gradle dependencies :**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
```

Android Studio version: *`AI 141.1962279 From Canary Channel`*

How to showing this on Android Studio Preview ? or Replacer for this?

**"android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout"**

Comment: Which version of sdk are you using?

Comment: **appcompat-v7:22.1.1** API:`22`

Comment: there are latest versions that that i Feel? this error is fixed buid tools version 22

Comment: There is an update for Android SDK tools to `24.3` from `24.1.2`.so, it means, i try to update this? also, Build tools 22.0.1 is availabe.so what we can ? thank you.

Comment: yes update to that and try

Comment: update both and check